# Hard drive spin, is detected in disk managment but faild to load itself

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, firmware

Yesterday evening I heard weird clicking from my 1TB Seagate hdd, when I found out today that when computer starts, the disk clicks about 10 times but does not load, it is not showing in windows explorer either in bios, but it is displayed in disk managment as unknown https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9bg8.jpg.

So I opened the top a little bit to see what was going on and found out that, on the PC start, disk normally spins, but read / write head about 10 times pass from base position to spindle, then stay in base position and disk stop spinning (it is doing on every boot even after I close it), also until this cycle is not completed the screen is stuck on motherboard boot screen. What could cause this error?

Comment: Head crash, failed read coil/head and now (due to dismantling it) dirt or dust under the read head. The drive is dead. Replace it.

Comment: You've disassembled the HDD? That would be an effective way to make sure it's dead.

Comment: @gronostaj Like, I do not disassembled it, I fixed the description

Comment: You broke the seal on the drive. You have effectively disassembled it and potentially let dust and other grit in. Even flakes from the sealing compound can be a problem. This is why drives have filter membranes around their "breather" holes.

Answer (score 2):

I have bad news: you've opened the drive, so now it's dead. Professional data recovery specialists may be able to help you. It won't be cheap.

HDDs are assembled in extremely clean conditions because any piece of dust can damage them. They are also very sensitive, even the tension on screws matters. Professional data recovery facilities use screw tension datasheets from disk manufacturers and special tools that can screw them in with proper force.

Your disk now has dust inside and you have no means to reassemble it properly.

---

When a HDD starts to sound weird but it's working, you should immediately make sure that your backups are up to date and restorable. If they are not, you should copy all data off the disk and replace it. Do not power off the computer and do not let the drive spin down for power saving, it may not start again.

If it sounds weird, doesn't work and your backups are outdated or missing, then immediately power off the computer, unplug the disk and let data recovery professionals handle it. Messing with it - even in software - can make things worse.